# Jenkins: Set job timeout from a variable

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I want my Jenkins' job to use timeout value from the build variable.
Tried the following but ended up with Java runtime error.

Note: I am triggering my jobs using the rest api.

[image: I want something similar to this]

Comment: What type of jenkins job are you running? A pipeline? This can be achieved easily via Declarative pipeline.

Comment: No. This is an individual job.